# sharing steam library between 2 OSs on a dual boot system

Tags: permissions, steam

I have a dual boot system, a windows 11 on my hdd and an ubuntu on my ssd. The problem is i want to use the storage of my hdd to store my games and even possibly play the games downloaded with windows with proton. But when i try to add the steam library to my ubuntu steam installation i get a `new steam library folder must be on a filesystem mounted with execute permissions` message. Is using games on two different OS is even possible and if it is, how do i do it?

EDIT: i found this command `sudo mount -o remount,rw '/mnt/2640D18E40D164D9'` that lets me do exactly that but i don't want to execute it evety time i reboot my pc. also i set my hard to auto mount at startup in the Disks GUI application. is there a way to add the permissions to there?